# Pandas: Groupby Fillna Not working

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, fillna

I have the following dataframe, which has about 4000 Tickers and in Total about 2 million rows:

```
Ticker      Date              Rank         
  1         01/01/2000         5            
  1         01/02/2000        NaN             
  2         01/01/2000         4            
  2         01/02/2000         2
```

I now run the following code to carryforward the Rank column, which works totally fine.:

```
import pandas as pd
df= df.sort_values(by=["Ticker", "Date"], ascending=[True,True])
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Ticker')['Rank'].fillna(value=None, method="ffill")
```

However, I now want to carryforward a different column. In order to create this column I do the following:

```
  import numpy as np
  df["Code"]=np.NaN
```

In this function I write some code that about 200 values will be replaced by 1 according to the date and ticker values in the df "add". This code worksand looks the following:

```
df["Code"][(df.Date == add) & (df["Ticker"] == column)] = 1
```

This makes my dataframe look like this:

```
Ticker      Date              Rank          Code      
  1         01/01/2000         5             NaN
  1         01/02/2000        NaN            NaN
  2         01/01/2000         4              1
  2         01/02/2000         2             NaN
```

Now, I want to carryforward this column, but the code takes forever.

```
import pandas as pd
df= df.sort_values(by=["Ticker", "Date"], ascending=[True,True])
df['Code'] = df.groupby('Ticker')['Code'].fillna(value=None, method="ffill")
```

I have ran it for two days and my pc crashed. There must be some mistake here in the way I am doing things, because the above carryforward runs so fast and this one does not even finish. I checked the dtype of "Code" and it is float64.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hard question why it run very long time. But I believe if groups are alredy sorted is possible add `sort=False` for improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

I try a bit improve your code with `sort=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html):

```
#convert column to datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
#ascending can be omit, because default value
df= df.sort_values(by=["Ticker", "Date"])

df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Ticker', sort=False)['Rank'].ffill()
add = '01/01/2000'
column = 2

df.loc[(df.Date == add) & (df["Ticker"] == column), "Code"] = 1

#sorting again is not necessary
df['Code'] = df.groupby('Ticker', sort=False)['Code'].ffill()
print (df)
   Ticker       Date  Rank  Code
0       1 2000-01-01   5.0   NaN
1       1 2000-01-02   5.0   NaN
2       2 2000-01-01   4.0   1.0
3       2 2000-01-02   2.0   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the problem is still with the ffill. Maybe it might be a problem that Ticker is datatype categorical?

Comment: I think not. Problem is no replace? It seems there is problem with data. Is possible create csv from data and test it? And if still problem and data not confidental is possible send me to my email in my profile?